# Limits of sequences by epsilon definition

Tags: limits

Show that if $$\lim_{\to\infty} \frac{3−_}{_}=1$$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} _= 3/2$$ where $a_n$ is a sequence of positive real numbers.

I need to show it by epsilon definition of limit.

My question is that, can I make an assumption like there is an $N$ s.t. for all $n>N$ with $a_n<2$ ?

Comment: You could, but I don't think it is necessary for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first review some definitions here, so that it is clear to you why these types of proof have to function the way they do. When a mathematician writes $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L,$$ this is just a special notation for saying that for all $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R},\epsilon\gt0$, there exists a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N},n\gt{N}$, $|a_n-L|\lt\epsilon$. As such, the statement $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3-a_n}{a_n}=1$$ is just saying that for all $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R},\epsilon\gt0$, there exists a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N},n\gt{N}$, $\left|\frac{3-a_n}{a_n}-1\right|\lt\epsilon$. Now notice that $\left|\frac{3-a_n}{a_n}-1\right|=\left|\frac{3}{a_n}-2\right|$. So this immediately constitutes a proof of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}{a_n}=2.$$ Also, $\left|\frac{3}{a_n}-2\right|=3\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac23\right|\lt\epsilon$ is equivalent to $\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac23\right|\lt\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Now, suppose $\epsilon=3\epsilon'$. $\epsilon\gt0$ if and only if $\epsilon'\gt0$, and this gives $\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac23\right|\lt\epsilon'$. So we have that for all $\epsilon'\in\mathbb{R},\epsilon'\gt0$, there exists a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N},n\gt{N}$, $\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac23\right|\lt\epsilon'$. Thus, this proves $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac23.$$ The inequality $\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac23\right|\lt\epsilon'$ is equivalent to $|a_n-\frac32|\lt\frac32\epsilon'|a_n|$. Thus, if you can bound $|a_n|$, from above, you can finish the proof.

Comment: If ı suppose  ||<2 for some N<n for all n. Proof is done. I did the same steps you do. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You are given your first line, so you are allowed to choose any $\epsilon'$ you want and ask for an $N'$ so that for $n \gt N'$ you have $ |\frac {3-a_n}{a_n}-1|\lt \epsilon'$.  The $\epsilon'$ you use may depend on the $\epsilon$ you are trying to satisfy in the second line.  If I give you an $\epsilon$ to satisfy for the second line, you should be able to compute how close $\frac {3-a_n}{a_n}$ has to be to $1$ so you can satisfy it.